# Having troubles starting mySQL

Tags: mysql

Sorry for any english mistakes; I'm trying to do my best.

I'm here because I'm having real troubles with mySQL. I downloaded successfully the software but I can't gain access to it. Even if mySQL seems to be [running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdomr.png)...

I tried to change the password *via* the command line but it didn't work either.

I used this    `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password test` .

But I always got this response:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

So what is wrong with my computer ? Or what am I doing wrong ?

I'm using the latest macOS Sierra version (10.12).

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, welcome!  Your English is good, no need to apologise.

Secondly, I'm guessing you are not aware that "StackOverflow" has a cousin website called "ServerFault", where this question would be better asked.  (StackOverflow targets software programming more than server/infrastructure related ones.)

That said, I'm happy to provide some help.

MySQL **is already running**.  Your screenshot demonstrates that it is.

The error you're receiving is not due to MySQL not running, but due to **invalid login credentials**.

Your command (`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password test`) is requesting a password change, but you aren't providing the *current `root` password*.  It needs both the new and the old...

Two obvious options:

1. If you know the *current* `root` password, supply it (`-p`, and you'll be prompted):  `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password test`
2. If you *don't know the current password*, force a reset using the MySQL instructions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

I've done it many times on Debian/RedHat, but never on MacOS.  The instructions under **"B.5.3.2.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems"** (see aforementioned link) should work with some prodding.

Feel free to comment back on this answer if you get stuck...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, I didn't know about "ServerFault", everything is a bit new for me. But thanks for the advice :)

That being said, I still can't manage to change my login credentials. I tried your first option because I know the current root password but I'm still stuck.

When I tried I got this :

note : "xpyhMllo****" is my **root password** and "hello01" would be **the new one**.

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u xpyhMllo****; -p hello01
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.7.16, for osx10.11 on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Administration program for the mysqld daemon.
Usage: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin [OPTIONS] command command....
  --bind-address=name IP address to bind to.
  -c, --count=#       Number of iterations to make. This works with -i
                      (--sleep) only.
  -#, --debug[=#]     This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.
  --debug-check       This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.
  --debug-info        This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.
  -f, --force         Don't ask for confirmation on drop database; with
                      multiple commands, continue even if an error occurs.
  -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.
  --character-sets-dir=name 
                      Directory for character set files.
  --default-character-set=name 
                      Set the default character set.
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -h, --host=name     Connect to host.
  -b, --no-beep       Turn off beep on error.
  -p, --password[=name] 
                      Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
                      not given it's asked from the tty.
  -P, --port=#        Port number to use for connection or 0 for default to, in
                      order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
                      /etc/services, built-in default (3306).
  --protocol=name     The protocol to use for connection (tcp, socket, pipe,
                      memory).
  -r, --relative      Show difference between current and previous values when
                      used with -i. Currently only works with extended-status.
  --secure-auth       Refuse client connecting to server if it uses old
                      (pre-4.1.1) protocol. Deprecated. Always TRUE
  -s, --silent        Silently exit if one can't connect to server.
  -S, --socket=name   The socket file to use for connection.
  -i, --sleep=#       Execute commands repeatedly with a sleep between.
  --ssl-mode=name     SSL connection mode.
  --ssl               Deprecated. Use --ssl-mode instead.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-ssl to disable.)
  --ssl-verify-server-cert 
                      Deprecated. Use --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY instead.
  --ssl-ca=name       CA file in PEM format.
  --ssl-capath=name   CA directory.
  --ssl-cert=name     X509 cert in PEM format.
  --ssl-cipher=name   SSL cipher to use.
  --ssl-key=name      X509 key in PEM format.
  --ssl-crl=name      Certificate revocation list.
  --ssl-crlpath=name  Certificate revocation list path.
  --tls-version=name  TLS version to use, permitted values are: TLSv1, TLSv1.1
  -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.
  -v, --verbose       Write more information.
  -V, --version       Output version information and exit.
  -E, --vertical      Print output vertically. Is similar to --relative, but
                      prints output vertically.
  -w, --wait[=#]      Wait and retry if connection is down.
  --connect-timeout=# 
  --shutdown-timeout=# 
  --plugin-dir=name   Directory for client-side plugins.
  --default-auth=name Default authentication client-side plugin to use.
  --enable-cleartext-plugin 
                      Enable/disable the clear text authentication plugin.
  --show-warnings     Show warnings after execution

Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
--------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
bind-address                      (No default value)
count                             0
force                             FALSE
compress                          FALSE
character-sets-dir                (No default value)
default-character-set             auto
host                              (No default value)
no-beep                           FALSE
port                              0
relative                          FALSE
secure-auth                       TRUE
socket                            (No default value)
sleep                             0
ssl                               TRUE
ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE
ssl-ca                            (No default value)
ssl-capath                        (No default value)
ssl-cert                          (No default value)
ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
ssl-key                           (No default value)
ssl-crl                           (No default value)
ssl-crlpath                       (No default value)
tls-version                       (No default value)
user                              xpyhMlloM7
verbose                           FALSE
vertical                          FALSE
connect-timeout                   43200
shutdown-timeout                  3600
plugin-dir                        (No default value)
default-auth                      (No default value)
enable-cleartext-plugin           FALSE
show-warnings                     FALSE

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
The following groups are read: mysqladmin client
The following options may be given as the first argument:
--print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
--no-defaults           Don't read default options from any option file,
                        except for login file.
--defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.
--defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read.
--defaults-group-suffix=#
                        Also read groups with concat(group, suffix)
--login-path=#          Read this path from the login file.

Where command is a one or more of: (Commands may be shortened)
  create databasename   Create a new database
  debug         Instruct server to write debug information to log
  drop databasename Delete a database and all its tables
  extended-status       Gives an extended status message from the server
  flush-hosts           Flush all cached hosts
  flush-logs            Flush all logs
  flush-status      Clear status variables
  flush-tables          Flush all tables
  flush-threads         Flush the thread cache
  flush-privileges      Reload grant tables (same as reload)
  kill id,id,...    Kill mysql threads
  password [new-password] Change old password to new-password in current format
  ping          Check if mysqld is alive
  processlist       Show list of active threads in server
  reload        Reload grant tables
  refresh       Flush all tables and close and open logfiles
  shutdown      Take server down
  status        Gives a short status message from the server
  start-slave       Start slave
  stop-slave        Stop slave
  variables             Prints variables available
  version       Get version info from server
-bash: -p: command not found
```

I don't really know what to do, I didn't thought it will be so hard to change a password and start MySQL ahah

Thanks for the time you takes for helping myself